# Why am I getting Floating-point exception (SIGFPE) here?

Tags: c++

The question is to Count the number of digits in N which evenly divides N. This is my code for it -

```
int evenlyDivides(int N){
    int temp = N;
    int residue;
    int count = 0;
    
    while(temp) {
        if(residue = temp % 10 && !(N % residue)) {
            count++;
        }
        temp /= 10;
    }
    
    cout << count;
}
```

If the residue variable ever turns out to be zero (Say N = 20) then it will fail the first condition of the if statement and hence never reaches the second condition of the if statement (where I am finding N % residue) Hence I should not get  Floating-point exception. What am I missing?

Comment: Try to be more generous with parentheses.

Comment: `residue = temp % 10 && !(N % residue)` doesn't really do what you think it does. It, actually, doesn't do anything anyone could possibly think it does, because it's undefined behavior.

Comment: I am going to be honest with you -- wouldn't it had been easier to just use parentheses to  get the desired result, than to go to StackOverflow, post a question, and in that process, get downvoted?  You used them here: `(N % residue)`, so why not use it on the other side of the `&&`?

Comment: See [C++ Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trick is understandable, but commonly this is bad practice to assign in *if* operator because of many possible types of traps. Your code is one of exemplars, why.

Compiler treats:

```
if(residue = temp % 10 && !(N % residue))
```

as

```
if(residue = (temp % 10 && !(N % residue)) )
```

which is quite logical in the light of the [C++ operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Possible solution:

```
int evenlyDivides(int N){
    int temp = N;
    int residue;
    int count = 0;
    
    while(temp) {
        residue = temp % 10;
        if (residue % 10 && !(N % residue)) {
            count++;
        }
        temp /= 10;
    }
    
    cout << count;
}
```

Comment: For a good answer, show how to fix the problem.

Comment: @PeteBecker, done, although I was sure that it is better to keep some space for homework to make sure that the person grasped it and learned by heart through practice. Note, his question was "What I am missing?", not "How to implement this?".

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I get when I build your app:

```
/*
 * BUILD:
 * c:\temp>g++ -g -Wall -pedantic -o x x.cpp
 * x.cpp: In function 'int evenlyDivides(int)':
 * x.cpp:9:20: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
 *     9 |         if(residue = temp % 10 && !(N % residue)) {
 *       |            ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 */
```

Here's where it crashes when I run it (with N=20):

```
if(residue = temp % 10 && !(N % residue)) { // SIGFPE here: temp=2, residue=0
```

SUGGESTED CHANGE:

```
if((residue = temp % 10) && !(N % residue)) { ... }
```